# Change vertical position of back button text in UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uinavigationbar

I've been able to change the vertical posiiton of the back button icon but not the text.

I'm using the layoutSubviews method in UINavigationBar:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    BOOL fixed = NO;
    NSArray *classNamesToReposition = @[@"_UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView", @"UINavigationButton", @"UINavigationItemButtonView"];
    for (UIView *view in [self subviews]) {
        if ([classNamesToReposition containsObject:NSStringFromClass([view class])] && !fixed) {
            CGRect frame = [view frame];
            if ([NSStringFromClass([view class]) isEqualToString:@"_UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView"]) {
                frame.origin.y = 14.5;
            } else if ([NSStringFromClass([view class]) isEqualToString:@"UINavigationButton"]) {
                frame.origin.y = 9.0;
            } else if ([NSStringFromClass([view class]) isEqualToString:@"UINavigationItemButtonView"]) {
                frame.origin.y = 5.0;
            }
            [view setFrame:frame];
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that any frame change I make on UINavigationItemButtonView does not seem to have any effect, nor any frame change I make on it's UILabel subview that is the actual button text. When I log the views the frames seem to be changing but the text is not moving in my view. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Jack, have you tried to place that code in `viewDidAppear:` instead? I tested on a project of mine and it does set the y position.

Answer (score 4):

You subclass a UINavigationBar called MyNavigationBar, in layoutSubviews, change the back indicator position.

```
for (UIView *view in [self subviews]) {
    CGRect frame = [view frame];
    if ([NSStringFromClass([view class]) isEqualToString:@"_UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView"]) {
        frame.origin.y = 19.5; //default is 11.5, move down by 8. 
    }
    [view setFrame:frame];
}
```

And you can change backBarItem's title position by adding this in applicationDidFinished.

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MyNavigationBar class], nil] setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, 8) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: Are those code blocks mutually exclusive; can you set the position using [UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn...] alone, or do you need to iterate through the views as well?

Comment: No,I have to add both of them, the first one is to change the back indicator(the back arrow),the second one is to change the backbarItem's title, here is an [example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uh0d7f258diynrs/VeticalPosition.zip?dl=0) in case you want to see how it works.

Comment: This is the great, but unfortunately this un-links the text from the back arrow making self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES; only hide the back arrow unfortunately. Have you figured out a solution to this dilemma?

Comment: @ChrisBrasino, no, you can ask another question, someone else will solve it.